# Ошибка Телеграм бот aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
import config
import logging
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from sqlighter import SQLighter


# задаем уровень логов
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# инициализируем бота
bot = Bot(token=config.API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# инициализируем соединение с БД
db = SQLighter('db.db')


# Команда активации подписки
@dp.message_handler(commands=['subscribe'])
async def subscribe(message: types.Message):
    if(not db.subscriber_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        # если юзера нет в базе, добавляем его
        db.add_subscriber(message.from_user.id)
    else:
        # если он уже есть, то просто обновляем ему статус подписки
        db.update_subscription(message.from_user.id, True)
    
    await message.answer("Вы успешно подписались на рассылку!\nЖдите, скоро выйдут новые обзоры и вы узнаете о них первыми =)")

# Команда отписки
@dp.message_handler(commands=['unsubscribe'])
async def unsubscribe(message: types.Message):
    if(not db.subscriber_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        # если юзера нет в базе, добавляем его с неактивной подпиской (запоминаем)
        db.add_subscriber(message.from_user.id, False)
        await message.answer("Вы итак не подписаны.")
    else:
        # если он уже есть, то просто обновляем ему статус подписки
        db.update_subscription(message.from_user.id, False)
        await message.answer("Вы успешно отписаны от рассылки.")

# получаем список подписчиков бота
        subscriptions = db.get_subscriptions()



                
                

# запускаем лонг поллинг
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
 executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

**Ошибка**

```
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-12' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=OperationalError('no such table: subscriptions')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ббб\bot.py", line 24, in subscribe
    if(not db.subscriber_exists(message.from_user.id)):
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ббб\sqlighter.py", line 18, in subscriber_exists
    result = self.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM `subscriptions` WHERE `user_id` = ?', (user_id,)).fetchall()
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: subscriptions
```

Comment: нет такой таблицы: `subscriptions`. Вы пытаетесь добавить юзера в таблицу, которая не создана

Comment: Она же есть в файле db